# how to paste column name before each cell in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
structure(list(PatientName = c("Tom Hardy", "Elma Fudd", "Bingo Man"
), HospitalNumber = c("H55435", "Y3425345", "Z343424"), Text = c("All bad. Not good", 
"Serious issues", "from a land far away"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

This dataframe actually comes from an original dataset where all the columns were merged with the column header as the delimiter as follows:

```
c("PatientName Tom Hardy HospitalNumber H55435 Text All bad. Not good", 
"PatientName Elma Fudd HospitalNumber Y3425345 Text  Serious issues", 
"PatientName Bingo Man HospitalNumber Z343424 Text  from a land far away"
)
```

How do I reconstruct with delimiter as the column name so I can end up with:

```
structure(list(X1_X2_X3 = c("PatientName Tom Hardy_HospitalNumber H55435_Text All bad. Not good", 
"PatientName Elma Fudd_HospitalNumber Y3425345_Text Serious issues", 
"PatientName Bingo Man_HospitalNumber Z343424_Text from a land far away"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"))
```

At the moment I am doing the following but it seems a bit messy. Is there a neater way?

```
    Interim<-data.frame(t(data.frame(apply(myDeets, 1, function(x) paste(names(x),x)))),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mynesdf<-tidyr::unite_(Interim, paste(colnames(Interim), collapse="_"), colnames(Interim))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `paste` the corresponding column names with the columns using `Map` and collapse it

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(Map(paste, names(df1), df1), sep="_"))
data.frame(X1_X2_X3 = unname(v1))

#                                                             X1_X2_X3
#1     PatientName Tom Hardy_HospitalNumber H55435_Text All bad. Not good
#2      PatientName Elma Fudd_HospitalNumber Y3425345_Text Serious issues
#3 PatientName Bingo Man_HospitalNumber Z343424_Text from a land far away
```

---

Or another option is to `stack` and then `paste`

```
v2 <- with(stack(df1), paste(ind, values))
unname(tapply(v2, rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), nrow(df1)), FUN = paste, collapse= "_"))
```